# FPDF MultiCell() text wrap error

Tags: fpdf

I'm using FPDF to generate PDF file. I'm saving a particular variable from a `<textarea>` then outputting it through `MultiCell()`.

The `<textarea>` input looks like this:

[image]

But the PDF file outputs like this:

[image]

It outputs unnecessary new lines which isn't included in the input.

My code looks like this:

```
$v=mysql_query("select * from postflight where reservno = '$_SESSION[ptrcode]'") or die(mysql_error());
$w=mysql_fetch_array($v);
$z=$w['prem']; //pilot remarks

$pr="PILOT REMARKS\n".$z;
$pdf->MultiCell(189, 8, $pr, 1, 1);
```

How can I fix this? Or is this the default spacing for text wrap in MultiCell()? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second parameter is the `height` parameter. You can reduce the spacing by lowering this value, for instance try setting it to `2` or `3`:

```
$pdf->MultiCell(189, 3, $pr, 1, 1);
```